# Multiple small led or one big one

Tags: led

I need some advice. I'm in the process of building a DIY aquarium fixture for my daughter. The light will be provided by 10W warm/cool white chips. My problem is this: I have several drivers for big 100W chips, the drivers specs are: 100W input voltage 85-265V, output voltage 30-36V, 3000mA. Can I power 10x10W chips on this instead of one big 100W? The 10W chips run at 9-11V, 900mA, so is this possible to run 10x 10W instead of one straight 100W?

Comment: Do LEDs replace tube ultra-violet lamps in fish tanks? UV does kill micro-organisms - I don't know if LEDs do this?

Comment: Some writing advice: capitalize units such as "W" and "V" for watts and volts. Milliams are expressed as "mA" not "Ma". You don't need a period after a question mark. (I've made these edits for you.)

Comment: @JYelton Mega-amps perhaps :-)

Comment: @Andyaka: UVA LEDs (which are expensive and rare) would.

Comment: @Anindo And even while offering writing advice I have a typo. Doh! I meant milliamp with a "p"! :)

Answer (score 1):

> **the driver specs are: output voltage 30-36 [V], 3000 [mA] ... The 10 [W] chips run at 9-11 [V], 900 [mA] ... so is this possible**

No.

Not the way I understand the scenario.

You'd have to run three 10W LEDs in series to match the voltage but the constant-current driver then has the wrong current.

You really need to buy or build drivers to specifically match the LEDs or LED-modules you are driving.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even *if* putting LEDs in parallel was not a terrible idea, there's no way you can arrange them to consume the 3000mA if each can only take 900mA; either you'd exceed it by 100mA (3 in parallel), or you'd undercurrent them by 50mA (4 in parallel). Undercurrentting LEDs is admittedly usually not a huge problem, but then you get back to using LEDs in parallel, which as mentioned is a terrible idea.